# Creating a new Work Record Type for Agile Accelerator - how to set a create/edit page?

Tags: custom-object, record-type

I need to create a new Work Record Type for Agile Accelerator. I've edited the Work custom object and added the new type under Record Types, as well as assigning it a layout under Page Layout Assignment.

When I go to create new Work, I can choose the new type from the dropdown, but when submitting I get the following error:

`Unexpected exception when directing you to the correct create/edit page. Exception:ADM_ApplicationException:[]: Unsupported record type specified: <new type>`

Record Types section of Work custom object:

[image: Record Type]

Page Layout Assignment:

[image]